# How to extract unique substring by linq

Tags: linq

I have an array

```
{ 
  Line.Column1.Pos,
  Line.Column1.Length,
  Line.Column2.Value,
  Line.Column3.Pos,
  Line.Column3.Length,
  line.Column5.Date
}
```

How to get a list of unque substrings, i.e.,
`{Column1,Column2,Column3,Column5 }` by Linq?

Comment: Can you post an example of the data, it is not clear what it looks like.

Comment: Unique items are a key.  So if you use a Groupby(x => new object[] {x.Column1,x.Column2,x.Column3,x.Column5})

Answer (score 1):

If you can get a string representation of the items in the array,

you could do this:

```
string[] items = 
{ 
    "Line.Column1.Pos", 
    "Line.Column1.Length", 
    "Line.Column2.Value", 
    "Line.Column3.Pos", 
    "Line.Column3.Length", 
    "line.Column5.Date" 
};

var distinctItems = items.
    Select(o => o.Split('.')[1]).
    Distinct().
    ToArray();
```